# Zurb Foundation Tabs Tabindex for keyboard accessibility

Tags: tabs, zurb-foundation, accessibility

In relation to Foundation tabs I am having some troubles with the tabindex and not being able to focus on the tabs when using a keyboard to navigate the page. The CMS I am using does not allow me to have the `is-active` class on the first tab. So I am using javascript to apply the `is-active` class dynamically. However, when I do so, the tabindex on the first tab anchor remains set as `tabindex="-1"` and therefore it is not possible navigate to the tabs using the keyboard.

When the `is-active` class is applied by default (in the demo example) Foundation takes care of setting `tabindex="0"` making it keyboard accessible. I have set up a demo:

```
<ul class="tabs" data-tabs="0btzm1-tabs" id="example-tabs" role="tablist">
 <li class="tabs-title is-active" role="presentation"><a href="#panel1" aria-selected="false" role="tab" aria-controls="panel1" id="panel1-label" tabindex="-1">Tab 1</a></li>
 <li class="tabs-title" role="presentation"><a href="#panel2" role="tab" aria-controls="panel2" aria-selected="false" id="panel2-label" tabindex="-1">Tab 2</a></li>
 <li class="tabs-title" role="presentation"><a href="#panel3" role="tab" aria-controls="panel3" aria-selected="false" id="panel3-label" tabindex="-1">Tab 3</a></li>
 <li class="tabs-title" role="presentation"><a href="#panel4" role="tab" aria-controls="panel4" aria-selected="true" id="panel4-label" tabindex="-1">Tab 4</a></li>
 <li class="tabs-title" role="presentation"><a href="#panel5" role="tab" aria-controls="panel5" aria-selected="false" id="panel5-label" tabindex="-1">Tab 5</a></li>
 <li class="tabs-title" role="presentation"><a href="#panel6" role="tab" aria-controls="panel6" aria-selected="false" id="panel6-label" tabindex="-1">Tab 6</a></li>
</ul>
```

https://codepen.io/benvivo/pen/rQQVmZ

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: In general, CSS has nothing to do with `tabindex`.  I'm guessing it's a timing issue.  Perhaps Foundation is checking if the `is-active` class is set, then setting tabindex for you, but the point where it's checking for is-active is before your javascript runs.  If there was a way for you to set is-active earlier in the cycle (`onload()`?), it might help.

Comment: If you poke through the code (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.5.0/js/foundation.min.js), which is run because of the keydown() handler on the `<li>` for each tab item, the `_handleTabChange()` function runs, which in turn runs `_collapseTab()` and `_openTab()` on the previous and newly selected tabs, respectively.  These latter two functions are the ones that set `tabindex`. There are a lot of references to "is-active" in that code too so perhaps you can see the timing of where "is-active" affects `_openTab()` being called, and thus setting `tabindex`.